# eclipse android string to Jsonarray

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, string

I got the following of my android app:

php file

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("tutorial",$con);
$r = mysql_query("select names from getdata where 1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{$out[]=$row;}
print(json_encode($out));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

then i got the following:

```
[{"0":"Sam","names":"Sam"},{"0":"Peter","names":"Peter"},{"0":"Smith","names":"Smith"},{"0":"Alfred","names":"Alfred"}]
```

as STRING variable "result".

i confirm that the app can connect and get the data.
BUT ...

```
try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            int count = jArray.length();

            for(int i=0; i<count;i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                temp += json_data.getString("names")+ ":";
            }
            arr = temp.split(":");
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("exception");
        }
```

this code keeps going to "exception"
how can I solve it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exception are your getting?

Comment: I don't know how to check the exception. I just know it keeps go to the code"catch{...}"

Comment: You can place a break point on the System.out.println line, run the app under debug mode and when the app gets to that line, check the value of e. Or better yet, `e.printStackTrace()` will print the exception to logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong variable in `split` method. Your string which you are adding with separator `:` is `temp` not `result` (it is the full json)

Replace

```
arr = result.split(":");
```

with

```
arr = temp.split(":");
```

Comment: sorry... this is my typo misstake

Comment: i change it, but i got the same result

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem then add `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block and post the output.

Comment: output means?? I am just a beginner

Comment: After adding `e.printStackTrace()` run the application. When your app will go into the catch block you will see some error logs in the logcat. Please post that.

Comment: it show 2 line: 
Got RemoteExeption sending setActive(false) notication to pid 3051 uid 10062
&
org.json.JSONException: Value<br of type java.lang.String cannot be convert to JSONArray

Comment: Got RemoteExeption sending setActive(false) notication to pid 3051 uid 10062                  &                   org.json.JSONException: Value<br of type java.lang.String cannot be convert to JSONArray

Comment: you are not getting the json you have posted. You are getting something which has "<br" in it. Please verify the json you are getting. Try to print it before you are using. Put a log and you will see what is the json you are getting but definitely its not what you have posted.

Comment: i got it, thanks a lot.
i find out that <br is inculde in the error message of php file,
so i change to use mysqli